# How do you add parameters to a count query ran on an excel spreadsheet via oledb?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, oledbcommand

I am trying to count the number of values on a column that are before a certain date. The below is my current attempt. I am able to run this no problem without the where section, however of course this is needed for the correct value to be returned.

1. string type = "Beacon Comm" this is the sheet name.
2. TargetBuildOledbConnection = `@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + FTPYTracker + "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';"`
3. string AssyColumn = "F" or whichever colum to search
4. DateTimeSelection = "03/01/2020 00:00:00" or data from a date picker in the same format.

   ```
   public double GetInProgressOledb(string type, OleDbConnection FTPYBuildOleDbConnection, string AssyColumn, DateTime Selection)
   {
       const string prodParamName = "@prod";
       double lastDayOfMonth = (new DateTime(Selection.Year, Selection.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)).ToOADate();
       using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand())
       {
           comm.Connection = FTPYBuildOleDbConnection;
           comm.CommandText = string.Format(ci, "SELECT Count(*) FROM [" + type + "$" + AssyColumn + ":" + AssyColumn + "] WHERE [" + AssyColumn + "$] = #" + lastDayOfMonth + "#");
           //comm.Parameters.Add(prodParamName, OleDbType.VarChar);
           //comm.Parameters[prodParamName].Value = lastDayOfMonth;
           double rowCount = Convert.ToDouble((int)comm.ExecuteScalar());
           return rowCount;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
comm.Parameters.Add("@prod", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = lastDayOfMonth;
```

Comment: I tried the following;

comm.CommandText = string.Format(ci, "SELECT Count(*) FROM [" + type + "$" + AssyColumn + ":" + AssyColumn + "] WHERE " + AssyColumn + "<{0}", prodParamName);

comm.Parameters.Add("@prod", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = lastDayOfMonth;

And it returned:  'No value given for one or more required parameters.'

Comment: Can you try with removing the IMEX=1 from the TargetBuildOledbConnection connection string.  It should be like "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; "Data Source='" + FilePath + 
"';Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"";

Comment: Unfortuantely no change at all with IMEX=1 removed